# Refactoring code for many to many field in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I need some help with refactoring the code for category and subcategories where subcategories are many to many field.

I need list of dictionaries with options for particular category, and label for only those subcategories which have options added for that category. I need output in this format

```
[{'sub_cat1': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'option1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'option2'}, {'label_for_sub_cat1': 'label1'}], 'sub_cat2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'option1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'option2'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'option3'}, {'label_for_sub_cat2': 'label2'}], 'sub_cat4': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'option1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'option2'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'option3'}, {'label': 'Label_for_sub_cat4'}]}]
```

I achieved this by using this code :

views.py

```
def post(self, request):
        category = request.GET.get('category')
        if category:
            category_list = list()
            sub_cat_list_1 = list()
            sub_cat_list_2 = list()
            sub_cat_list_3 = list()
            sub_cat_list_4 = list()
            category_data_dict={}
            category_data = Categories.objects.get(id = category)               
            for value in category_data.sub_cat1.all():
                sub_cat_list_1.append({
                    'id':value.id,
                    'name':value.field_name
                })
            if sub_cat_list_1:
                sub_cat_list_1.append({'label':category_data.label_for_sub_cat1})
            category_data_dict['sub_cat1'] = sub_cat_list_1
            for value in category_data.sub_cat2.all():
                sub_cat_list_2.append({
                    'id':value.id,
                    'name':value.field_name
                })
            if sub_cat_list_2:
                sub_cat_list_2.append({'label':category_data.label_for_sub_cat2})
            category_data_dict['sub_cat2'] = sub_cat_list_2
            for value in category_data.sub_cat3.all():
                sub_cat_list_3.append({
                    'id':value.id,
                    'name':value.field_name
                })
            if sub_cat_list_3:
                sub_cat_list_3.append({'label':category_data.label_for_sub_cat3})
            category_data_dict['sub_cat3'] = sub_cat_list_3
            for value in category_data.sub_cat4.all():
                sub_cat_list_4.append({
                    'id':value.id,
                    'name':value.field_name
                })
            if sub_cat_list_4:
                sub_cat_list_4.append({'label':category_data.label_for_skin_type})
            category_data_dict['sub_cat4'] = sub_cat_list_4
            category_list.append(category_data_dict.copy())
print(category_list)
```

This is models.py

```
class SubCat1(models.Model):

    field_name = models.CharField(_('field name'),max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'),auto_now_add = True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(_('modified on'),auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field_name)


class SubCat2(models.Model):

    field_name = models.CharField(_('field name'),max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'),auto_now_add = True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(_('modified on'),auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field_name)


class SubCat3(models.Model):

    field_name = models.CharField(_('field name'),max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'),auto_now_add = True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(_('modified on'),auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field_name)


class SubCat4(models.Model):

    field_name = models.CharField(_('field name'),max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'),auto_now_add = True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(_('modified on'),auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field_name)


class Categories(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('category name'),max_length=20)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'),auto_now_add = True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'),auto_now = True)
    sub_cat1 = models.ManyToManyField(SubCat1, blank=True)
    label_for_sub_cat1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_cat2 = models.ManyToManyField(SubCat2, blank=True)
    label_for_sub_cat2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_cat3 = models.ManyToManyField(SubCat3, blank=True)
    label_for_sub_cat3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_cat4 = models.ManyToManyField(SubCat4, blank=True)
    label_for_sub_cat4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

I would be great help if someone can help me refactor this code as this doesn't seem like a proper way of doing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try modular approach for your View where you can define a method with general params for each list. Just pass and process the list.
To refactor your models, I would like to refer you to look into the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):

field_name = models.CharField(_('field name'),max_length=100)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'),auto_now_add = True)
modified_on = models.DateTimeField(_('modified on'),auto_now = True)
label = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.field_name)

class Categories(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(_('category name'),max_length=20)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'),auto_now_add = True)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'),auto_now = True)
sub_categories = models.ManyToManyField('SubCategory', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

views.py

```
def post(self, request):
category_list = list()
category = request.GET.get('category')
if category:  
    category_data = Categories.objects.get(id=category)               
    for sub_category in category_data.sub_categories.all():
        category_list.append({
            'id':sub_category.id,
            'name':sub_category.field_name,
            'label': sub_category.label
            })
print(category_list)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. actually, its a requirement to have four different models for subcategories because of project structure, so cannot have a single model for sub categories.